# Favicon of React App won't change in Firefox, Chrome works however

Tags: reactjs, firefox, favicon

I have a react app for which I switched the favicon.ico in the public folder from the default react logo to a custom favicon. In Chrome it is showing just fine, in Firefox however it refuses to update to my custom favicon. How is that possible? I removed the original file.
`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be cached by the browser, try going into the Firefox preferences and then clearing data in the privacy & security menu.